# how to fit text in a row in screen

Tags: react-native

There is View contains an image and Text, If Image removed Text fits screen as it suppose to be, but since Image gets '75' of current row some part of text goes out of screen. Actually all it must do is end line 75px earlier..

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }}
            source={{ uri: 'https://cdnhsys.saglik.gov.tr/Content/img/login/yeni-logo.png' }}
          />
          <View style={{left:10, justifyContent:'center', , flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:12, color:'white'}}>
             This is sample text 'this text' not seem in screen.
          </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
```

How to make this text fits in screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:"center"}}>
  <View>
    <Text>hello</Text>
  </View>
  <View ><Image
        style={{ width: 75, height: 75 }}
        source={{ uri: 'https://cdnhsys.saglik.gov.tr/Content/img/login/yeni-logo.png' }}
      /></View>

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question, I think this may help you

```
 <Text style={{fontSize:12, color:'black',width:Dimensions.get('screen').width-85}} >
           This is sample text 'this text' not seem in screen
       </Text>
```

You can experiment and set width as you like